# Invariant default type for enums in Scala 3

Tags: scala, enums, gadt, dotty, scala-3

Scala 3 now has an improved way to define ADTs.
A syntactic sugar that removes all the hassle of doing them with the usual `sealed trait` way.

So I'll explain my question with an example

```
enum Adt[+A]{
    case Option1
    case Option2
}
```

In this case `Option1` and `Option2` are of type `Adt[Nothing]`, because the type parameter `A` is covariant.

If the enum were contravariant, they would be of type `Adt[Any]`.

But what if it is invariant?

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Dotty 0.27.0-RC1, this is an error:

```scala
scala> enum Adt[A]{
     |     case Option1
     |     case Option2
     | }
2 |    case Option1
  |    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |    cannot determine type argument for enum parent class Adt,
  |    type parameter type A is non variant
3 |    case Option2
  |    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |    cannot determine type argument for enum parent class Adt,
  |    type parameter type A is non variant
```